# Radio buttons not displaying in nested ionic list

Tags: list, ionic2

I have a nested list with text and radio button that is not displaying in Ionic 2.

This is a bit of a desperate situation and I have been sitting for hours with this. Worst of all it used to work but since updating the framework to  `2.0.0-rc.6` it doesn't render anymore.

```
<ion-list class="opl-question-container">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let opl of Opls">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let q of opl.Questions" class='questionDescibe' text-wrap>
                <ion-list-header>
                    {{ q.QuestionName }}
                </ion-list-header>
                <ion-list radio-group text-wrap>
                    <ion-item *ngFor="let a of q.Answers">
                        <ion-label class="opl-question-answers">{{a.AnswerDescription}}</ion-label>
                        <ion-radio [value]='a.AnswerDescription'></ion-radio>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

If I replace the ion-label and ion-radio with just text it does render.

Any advice perhaps on how to solve this issue?

this is the structure of the Opls

```
{
"Opl_Id": 103,
"OplDescription": "Lesson One",
"Questions": [
  {
    "Question_Id": 11,
    "QuestionName": "1. How are you today?",
    "QuestionDescription": "1. How are you today?",
    "QuestionType": "radio",
    "Answers": [
      {
        "Answer_Id": 33,
        "AnswerDescription": "I am well thanks",
        "Correct": false,
        "DateCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "DateUpdated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Answer_Id": 34,
        "AnswerDescription": "Could be better but not too bad",
        "Correct": false,
        "DateCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "DateUpdated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Answer_Id": 35,
        "AnswerDescription": "Not too good",
        "Correct": true,
        "DateCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "DateUpdated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Thank you

Comment: Would it be possible to see the structure for `Opls`? Also .. not sure but the  first `ion-item` seems redundant, might be better to just replace it with an `ion-col` or `div`

Comment: Hi there, I updated the question, thanks. I will look into the ion-col but did trying using divs ...no luck yet. I think it is a quirk with Ionic 2 because as soon as ion-radio is added everything just dissapears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using this structure

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let opl of Opls">
  <ion-col *ngFor="let q of opl.Questions">
    <ion-list radio-group>

      <ion-list-header>
        {{q.QuestionName}}
      </ion-list-header>

      <ion-item *ngFor="let a of q.Answers">
        <ion-label class="opl-question-answers">{{a.AnswerDescription}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio [value]='a.AnswerDescription'></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
</ion-col>
```

This replaces the psuedo `ion-list` and `ion-item` which i think in the nested repeat on the `*ngFor` it was causing conflict with the layout display

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help...I will follow this example as soon as I am in front of my computer again